# jQueryUI tooltip jumps around

Tags: jquery, tooltip

When I repeatably scroll over an element the [jQuery tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) seems to jump around. I thought maybe it was because it was colliding with itself, so I set the collision option to `none` but that didn't help.

Is this a bug? How can I get it to not jump around?

Comment: Can you share the code you're having trouble with, and perhaps a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) example?

Comment: it's my first time using JSFiddle, hope it worked http://jsfiddle.net/kteXP/1/

Comment: On my page the position of the tip depended on the size of the tip that had just been shown. With 3 item in the list if I hovered over the first and then the second the tip was always in the same position, and always in a different position if I went from the third back to the second. And a different position again after going away from the list and coming back to item 2. The offset was equal to the size of the previously shown tooltip. Sounds like a bug to me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I set the .ui-tooltip class to have `position: absolute` it seems to have worked, not sure if there will be unwanted consequences though?

Comment: Mine was already set to position: absolute and this didn't solve it. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 8):

It seems that happygilmore's method no longer works (and as he said, is also a risky approach). I suggest using the [Tooltip Widget API](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/) by setting the following options:

```
position: {
    collision: 'none'
},
hide: false
```

The [`collision: none`](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) option stops jQuery UI from trying to do anything fancy to resolve collisions and [`hide: false`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-hide) stops it from using a fade animation to slowly remove the tooltip; the delay of which causes the collision to occur in the first place. In my opinion it looks just fine without the fade animation.

Comment: The `collision: none` meant the tooltip went off the edge of the page, for me, but the `hide: false` seemed to stop the jumping around.